# Home.js:45 Error while fetching data from API: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON

Tags: reactjs

This is my backend api.I am using MYSQL database in xampp.this is a react project

```
app.get("/getdata",async(req,res)=>{

  let connection;


  try {
      connection = await pool.getConnection();
      const [result] = await connection.query("SELECT * FROM Products");
      console.log("Data retrieved");
      res.status(200).json({ status: 200, data: result });
      // ,(err,result)=>{
      //     if(err){
      //         console.log("error")
      //     }else{
      //         console.log("data get")
      //         res.status(201).json({status:201,data:result})
      //     }
      // })
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error retrieving data from the database:", error);
    res.status(500).json({ status: 500, error: error.message });
  } finally {
    if (connection) {
      connection.release(); // Release the connection back to the pool
    }
  }
});
```

I have used a useEffect hook in my frontend to consolelog whether data is fetched properly or not.

```
useEffect(() => {
    // Define a function to fetch data from the /getdata API
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch('/getdata'); // Assuming your API is served from the same host
        if (response.ok) {
          const data = await response.json();
          //setProducts(data.data);
          console.log("Data retrieved from API:", data);
        } else {
          console.error("Failed to fetch data from API");
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error while fetching data from API:", error);
      }
    };

    console.log("I am here"); // Print "I am here" in the console

    fetchData(); // Call the fetchData function when the component mounts
  }, []);
```

This is the frontend part.

I am using bodyparser and express too.But why the syntax error ?Please can you tell me the correct code .

I tried this and got the error.I tried to retrieve data from database.And wanted to console log in the frontend page(on loading or startup(whenever the page is loaded)) that the data was fetched from api correctly

Comment: You are getting an error page not a message here.

Comment: Dump this into a string to see what the page is, could be incorrectly calling the API and you are getting an error from IIS

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. can you show me where the error might be?

Comment: You are getting back a web page and not JSON so it will not parse. Export the error you are getting and evaluate it in a file so it is easier to read. Post the entire error response.